# results of ls in one line when the output goes to a file

Tags: linux, ls

ls returns files in a line when it connects to stdout.

```
$ ls
a b c
```

when it redirects to a file

```
$ ls > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
a
b
c
```

I realize the option `-C`

```
$ ls -C > hoge.txt
$ cat hoge.txt
a b c
```

However, when a list of files has many, `ls` puts carriage returns in the list.
like

```
 a b c d e f g h
 i j k l ....
```

How can I have

```
 a b c d e f g h i j k l.....(without \n)
```

Comment: Use the first approach, then replace `\n` with space?

Comment: no option helps that?

Comment: I'm not a friend of such special options, you need to remember them and there are way too many ways to format output. Maybe there is such an option, but unless (computational) efficiency is a concern, I guess it's much more (personal) efficient to build your solution with `ls` and `sed`.

Comment: Why not `(printf " %s" $(ls dir)) > file`

Comment: Post-filtering the output with `tr` the best way to go.   Next is to write a simple wrapper around `opendir/readdir` (which is all `ls` should be, but you wouldn't know that since you've grown accustomed to bells and whistles).  The third solution is to examine the output and enter the data in the form you want by hand (ie, type it!).   In a distant 4th place comes the task of wading through the gnu ls documentation to try to find an option that does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if `ls` provides an option for that and I haven't looked it up.
Since the question doesn't specifically ask for a very fast or computationally efficient solution, I recommend to synthesize a command using `ls` and `sed`:

```
ls "$dir" | sed -z 's/\n/ /g'
```

It takes the `ls` output and replaces all newlines `\n` with spaces.
The `-z` switch is required because otherwise `sed` would work line-oriented, and `sed`'s pattern matcher would never see the `\n`.
You will have a problem if one of your filenames in `$dir` contains spaces.

If computational efficiency is a concern, I recommend searching for such an option (`man ls`) or writing a program that does just that (using, e.g., the `C` language).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution,

```
echo -E $(ls -1 dir) > file.txt
```

where

-1 print o/p in single-column

-E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes

Source: [this](https://serverfault.com/a/829092/553536) serverfault page

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
ls | xargs > foo.txt
```